# Remove First Leading Number Characters & Space

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling to find a solution for the below problem (see picture):
https://prnt.sc/TpHBLu-FRQv_

The ideal solution will be either on Power Query or Excel itself.

The issue it's the following:
I have a list of products which include a leading number at the beginning as well as a "." and a space after. My intention it's to find a solution to remove the leading numbers, the dot and the space without removing the products which have no numbers at the beginning (see picture).

https://prnt.sc/6Gg6mEZeeYcu

I've tried with Power Query by "splitting" the columns with the "Position" and all the other functions under the "Split Column" button but they are not very useful.

I've tried to import the table into Excel after finishing the edits on Power Query and applying the "Text to Columns" button function but it's not useful either as it removes the letters from the products which don't have a numeration at the beginning.

Maybe someone with experience might give me a hand and make it as easy as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Your first screenshot doesn't opens it shows nothing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Microsoft-365 then could try `TEXTSPLIT()` with delimeter `.`  (dot and space).

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A2,". "),,-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually accomplish this using `POWER QUERY` as well as using Excel Formulas in `MS365`

---

Using **MS365 Formulas** - `TEXTAFTER()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=TEXTAFTER(A4,". ",1,,,A4)
```

---

Or, if you want to `#Spill!`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=TEXTAFTER(A4:A9,". ",1,,,A4:A9)
```

---

Using **Power Query**

[image]

---

Open a blank query and add the **M-Code** in the **Advanced Editor** from **Home Tab** --> Change the `Table Name` as required per your suit.

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Output", each if Text.AfterDelimiter([PART NUMBER],". ",0)="" then [PART NUMBER] else Text.AfterDelimiter([PART NUMBER],". ",0))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

---

In **PQ Editor Window**:

[image]

---